# Divisibility of group exponents when the subgroup has finite index.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group (not necessary finite) and $H$ a subgroup of $G$ of index $n$ such that [exp](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group) $(H)<+\infty$ .

> Show that $$\exp(G)<+\infty$$ and $$\exp(G)\mid\exp(H)\cdot n.$$

Remarks.

- The case when $H$ is normal is a consequence of the group structure on the cosets.
- If $g\in G$, in general $g^n\not\in H$, for example $G=S_5$, $H=S_4$ and $g=(12)(345)$.

Comment: Yes, I've added the link now.

Comment: For the first point consider the action of $G$ on the cosets of H $$g \cdot kH = gkH$$ Then the kernel of the action is the so called core($H$)

Comment: core($H$)$ \triangleleft G$ and core($H$)$\subseteq H$. Set core($H$) $= K$. Then $G/K$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$ and so $$g^{n!} \in K \subseteq H $$ for all $g \in G$

Comment: This implies that $\exp(G)$ is finite

Comment: Yes, now we have proved that $$\exp(G)\mid\exp(H)\cdot n!$$, how to conclude?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has been proved already in the comments that ${\rm exp}(G)$ is finite, so let's assume that. Let $g \in G$. By factorizing $|g|$, $n$ and ${\rm exp}(H)$ into prime powers, we can easily reduce to the case when $|g|$ is a power of a prime $p$.

In the permutation action of $G$ on the cosets of $H$, $g$ maps to a product of cycles each of length a power of $p$. Let $p^a$ be the highest power of $p$ that divides $n$. Then some cycle of $g$ in this action must have length $p^b$ with $b \le a$, and so $g^{p^a}$ fixes a point and hence lies in a conjugate of $H$. So $|g^{p^a}|$ divides ${\rm exp}(H)$ and we are done.